# How to deploy OpenProject on Heroku?

Tags: docker, cloud, heroku

I want to deploy project management software **OpenProject** on Heroku cloud through docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  openproject:
    container_name: openproject
    image: openproject/community:8
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./static:/var/db/openproject
      - ./logs:/var/log/supervisor
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main
```

I can't understand how to deploy without Dockerfile. Should I use *git* or *Container* *Registry*?

Comment: did you ever figure with out?